# Neo4j expand path and return distinct nodes and relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have given one or more start nodes (by ID) and I need to expand over one or more hops and return one result with an array of distinct nodes and and array of distinct relationships.

I can do this either via [`apoc.path.expand()`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-querying/expand-paths/) or [`apoc.path.subgraphAll()`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-querying/expand-subgraph/), but either way it produces multiple rows for each expanded path, and therefore may contain duplicate nodes. To reduce the multiple rows into one row, I have used `collect()` with `apoc.coll.toSet()` and `apoc.coll.flatten()` to remove duplicates from the `nodes` and `relationships` array:

**apoc.path.subgraphAll:**

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) IN $ids
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, { minLevel: 1, maxLevel: 2 }) YIELD nodes, relationships
WITH collect(nodes) as nodes, collect(relationships) as relationships
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(nodes)) as nodes, apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(relationships)) as relationships
```

**apoc.path.expand:**

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) IN $ids
CALL apoc.path.expand(n, null, null, 1, 2) YIELD path
WITH collect(nodes(path)) as nodes, collect(relationships(path)) as relationships
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(nodes)) as nodes, apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(relationships)) as relationships
```

Is there another way to remove the duplicates from the two arrays or to query the nodes and relationships?

Comment: can you try collect(DISTINCT nodes)?

Comment: `DISTINCT` won't work in this case, because the APOC procedure returns multiple rows, each row has an `nodes` array and `collect()` would simply combine each `nodes` array into an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case does not need APOC at all. This may work for you:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*..2]-(m)
WHERE ID(n) IN $ids
WITH COLLECT(n)+COLLECT(m) AS nodes0, COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS relationships
UNWIND nodes0 AS node
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT node) as nodes, relationships
```

The query uses a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern to find all relevant paths of length 1 or 2. Then it collects all the nodes in the paths, [unwinds](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) them, and returns a collection of distinct nodes.

As shown, returning a collection of distinct relationships is straightforward.